# Is there any power plug that passengers may use on the Yangon Circular Train?

Tags: trains, power, myanmar, yangon

Is there any power plug that passengers may use on the [Yangon Circular Train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangon_Circular_Railway)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many users on [tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g294190-i9408-k11067251-Quick_question_Do_trains_have_power_outlets-Myanmar.html) seem to agree that there aren't any power sockets anywhere on the train.

> none of the trains i have taken had power outlets

> No power outlets in Myanmar train.

> On the train now, I can confirm no outlets!! Not even close!

However as it is developing, they might add them in.